# correct approach to accessing the const keys in SPTAudioStreamingController for trackMetadata dictionary?

Tags: ios, metadata, spotify

What's the correct approach to accessing the const keys in SPTAudioStreamingController for trackMetadata dictionary?

In my .m file, I've tried:

```
#import <Spotify/SPTAudioStreamingController.h>
```

So that I can do something like:

```
[trackMetadata objectForKey: SPAudioStreamingMetadataTrackURI]
```

But, no dice, I get "Use of undeclared identifier 'SPAudioStreamingMetadataTrackURI'"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the header file you're importing, you'll see that you're missing a "T" at the start:

```
[trackMetadata objectForKey:SPTAudioStreamingMetadataTrackURI];
```